# Alloy UI Scheduler Multiple Day Event for selected Time Period

Tags: liferay, alloy-ui

The problem being faced with Alloy UI Scheduler is that, I am unable to select multiple day event for a selected time period for example from 12-Aug2014 to 15 Aug 2014 with timing from 1:00 PM to 5:00 PM everyday from 12th to 15th Aug 2014. As of now current alloy ui scheduler is taking it as a allDay event which should not be the case as shown in image attached.

Please let me know how to achieve the above. [image: All Day Event in AlloyUI Scheduler]

Comment: Rohan, is this a question about using the AlloyUI `Scheduler` or do you want to set these events programmatically?

Comment: @stiemannkj1, thanks for responding the question is how multiple/recurring event can be set in alloy ui scheduler.

Comment: Rohan, do you want to set the event via JavaScript?

Comment: If its not an inbuilt feature of AlloyUI scheduler, than javascript or jquery is the way. @stiemannkj1

Answer (score 0):

The best way that I could find to do this is to use a `for` loop. For your specific example of events from 1pm to 5pm from Aug 12th to the 15th, you could create a `for` loop similar to this one:

```
var events = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

    events.push({
        content: 'Repeating Event',
        endDate: new Date(2014, 7, 12 + i, 17),
        startDate: new Date(2014, 7, 12 + i, 13)
    });
}

new Y.Scheduler({
    // ...
    date: new Date(2014, 7, 11),
    items: events,
    render: true
    // ...
});
```

Here's a full example with a runnable [AlloyUI `Scheduler`](http://alloyui.com/examples/scheduler/) (scroll down to see the events that start at 1pm):

```js
YUI().use('aui-scheduler', function (Y) {

    var events = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

        events.push({
            content: 'Repeating Event',
            endDate: new Date(2014, 7, 12 + i, 17),
            startDate: new Date(2014, 7, 12 + i, 13)
        });
    }

    new Y.Scheduler({
        boundingBox: '#boundingBox',
        date: new Date(2014, 7, 10),
        items: events,
        render: true,
        views: [new Y.SchedulerWeekView()]
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/stiemannkj1/701826667a70997013605edcd37e92a6/raw/469fe1ae297e72a5a80eb9015003b7b04eac735e/alloy-ui-3.0.1_aui_aui-min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/stiemannkj1/90be22de7f48c729b443af14796d91d3/raw/a9f35ceedfac7fc0559b121bed105eaf80f10bf2/aui-css_css_bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"></link>
<div id="boundingBox"></div>
```

If this solution is not good enough, you may want to check out the [`Scheduler` API docs](http://alloyui.com/api/modules/aui-scheduler.html). [`SchedulerEvent`](http://alloyui.com/api/classes/A.SchedulerEvent.html) has a [`repeated` attribute](http://alloyui.com/api/classes/A.SchedulerEvent.html#attr_repeated) that may be what you are looking for (**Note:** I could not get the `repeated` attribute to work in the way that I expected for your use case).